# What is the equivalent of Linux's "~" (tilde) in Windows?

Tags: windows, linux, command-line

In Linux, we can go to the user home by entering the tilde (`~`) character after `cd`:

```
cd ~
```

How to do the same in Windows?

Each time, I need to type:

```
cd C:\Document and Settings\freewind
```

That's too boring.

Comment: Consider using cygwin ?

Comment: actually, '~' is the default for 'cd' under most Linux shells, so just 'cd' would suffice to go to your homedir

Comment: @Arnout: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998626/meaning-of-tilde-in-linux-bash-not-home-directory

Comment: The answer is simply "cd ~".. means, you can use the same command in Windows too. But, you shouldn't try this command in CMD because its out-dated now & its development is discontinued by Microsoft. Use "Windows PowerShell" and the same command will work smoothly.

Comment: @SachinShekhar Unless I'm mistaken, PowerShell doesn't even ship with Windows. If he has to install an application, he may as well just install cygwin.

Comment: PowerShell ships with Win7+

Comment: @weberc2 Powershell is included in all Windows since Windows 7

Comment: @weberc2 PowerShell is now the default on Windows 10.

Comment: It's a feature of shells, not of the kernel, so the "equivalent of Linux's `~` (tilde) in Windows" is exactly the tilde, you just need to use a shell that supports it.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`cd /d "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%"` would do it -- but I 'm not sure if you consider it an improvement.

You can also define an alias for the above command:

```
doskey cdhome=cd /d "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%"
```

After this, it's simply `cdhome`.

Comment: @Freewind: You gotta love the default Windows shell.

Comment: Just wondering what is the difference between `%USERPROFILE%` and `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`

Comment: @abatishchev: Good question. [This question](http://serverfault.com/questions/85713/when-would-the-windows-environment-variable-be-homepath) on SF seems to indicate that %USERPROFILE% is preferable.

Comment: You can also use cd~ as the macro name, instead if cdhome.

Comment: @Jon, I found when I close the shell, the `doskey` won't work anymore. How to make it always available?

Comment: @Freewind: You will need to set it up to execute whenever a shell is started, which [can be accomplished using the registry](http://sourcedaddy.com/windows-7/using-autorun-execute-commands-when-command-prompt-starts.html).

Comment: @abatishchev: Windows NT accounts can have a "home directory" path attached which is separate from the "profile directory". The profile keeps your *settings* (Registry), application data, and such. The home directory, on the other hand, is for *your own files* -- when a program displays the "Open/Save" dialog for the first time, it will start at the home directory. (Windows 95/98 used it somewhat differently; can't remember the specifics.) This is useful in Active Directory environments, for storing files on a network share but keeping the profile local.

Comment: @jftuga: Or even `~`.

Comment: Why not just create a batch script and place it in your path? `~.bat` could contain `cd %USERPROFILE%`, and it would be accessible by typing `~` at your command prompt. Furthermore, it would be valid outside of your shell without registry hacks.

Comment: @user1686 and how exactly do I separate those directories? or is it not supported in later OS versions?

Comment: @Unknow0059: Look for the "Profile" tab in `dsa.msc` for AD accounts, `lusrmgr.msc` for local accounts.

Comment: For posteriority: The profile tab can be found after clicking and opening the Properties of an entry in the results list of lusrmgr.

Answer (score 75):

You can use `cd /d %USERPROFILE%` if you use cmd.

or you can use `cd ~` if you use PowerShell.

Comment: +1 but also add quotes around the variable (maybe it's `c:\documents and settings\...`, the spaces will break it unless it's quoted)

Comment: @Jon: `cd` is an exception. Since it always takes a single argument, quoting is not necessary. (On Windows, programs and built-ins must parse their command line themselves, the shell does not do it.) Always quoting paths *is* a good practice, however.

Comment: @barlop: usually [CommandLineToArgvW()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647232.aspx); the CLR/MinGW/Cygwin runtimes also use their own equivalent automatically before calling main(). *Some* programs, however, have parsers written entirely from scratch, for example, `cmd.exe` itself and its wacky `/c`.

Comment: @grawity well, I don't see why one would call it wacky 'cos cmd /? shows that /c or /k is the last switch to use, and whatever follows /c or /k is a string. So i'd expect what follows the /c or /k to be combined but not with that which precedes it, the /c or /k.  Putting quotes in for that which is after /c or /k would be superfluous.

Comment: @barlop: Not if you're trying to use quotes (or redirection) as part of the given command. Is it `/c "C:\foo bar\baz" "my file.txt"` or `/c "\"C:\foo bar\baz\" \"my file.txt\""` or `/c ""C:\foo bar\baz" "my file.txt""`? What's even worse is that the parsing depends on whether `/s` was specified earlier, the presence of special characters, whether the executable is named `C:\foo bar\baz` or just `C:\foo`...

Comment: @TheLQ A batch script is even easier still. I can accomplish the same result by typing a single character. See my answer below for a description.

Comment: `::{59031a47-3f72-44a7-89c5-5595fe6b30ee}` in windows explorer is  the same as pasting `%USERPROFILE%`

Answer (score 13):

One possibility is to use the `subst` command from a command prompt:

```
subst z: C:\Document and Settings\freewind
```

Any time you navigate to drive Z:, you'll be looking at your user folder.

The downside is that you need to run it every time you log in. I used a batch file and just put it in my startup folder, but there are probably more elegant solutions to this.

The benefit is that unlike a doskey alias, it works universally (windows explorer, browse dialog, etc.), not just when changing directories at the command prompt. It's especially helpful for old programs with old browse dialogs that have drive letters at the topmost level, rather than "desktop".

Comment: You can map a drive and make it automatically remap after login. No need to use subst

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc It may not be entirely logical, but I tend to avoid windows network share things unless I really have to use them. I feel like performance and reliability is... unpredictable? By all means if you have an alternative, nay better, way of doing it, please post it in its own answer for the benefit of everyone :)

Comment: No need for more software utilities. Mapping is the most efficient option.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this:

```
cd %homepath%
```

Comment: This will break if you're on a different drive - e.g. you're on `E:` and your homedir is on `C:`

Answer (score 5):

You can create a batch file called `~.bat` containing

```
@echo off
cd /d %USERPROFILE%
```

And add it to your PATH variable (Start->[right-click on "Computer"]->Properties->"Advanced System Settings"[in left column]->"Environment Variables"

From there, just edit your PATH variable to include the folder containing your `~.bat` file. (This allows you to invoke your script from anywhere using just the filename--not the absolute path to the file)

Also, make sure your `PATHEXT` environment variable contains `.BAT` somewhere (this allows you to type `~` instead of `~.bat`).

When you need to use it, simply enter `~` at the command prompt. This solution is persistent--you won't have to set it up every time you launch a shell, and you won't need to hack your registry.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, I'm unaware of a perfect solution but there are a couple of hacky options:

**Option 1: Set ~ to be a command alias with doskey**

```
doskey ~=cd /d %USERPROFILE%
```

This will enable you to simply type `~` and have it chdir to your homedir.

```
C:\>~
C:\Users\a>
```

Obviously, this shortens the number of keystrokes to get home (even compared to Linux), but is less robust since you can't really use it as part of another path or do much with it beyond just cd'ing home.

**Option 2: Set ~ to be a variable**

Another option, if you want a more robust option is to set a var:

```
set ~="%USERPROFILE%"
```

but using this would be used like:

```
E:\>cd /d %~%
C:\Users\a>
```

It can also be injected into most paths and doesn't limit you to simply cd'ing home.

**Both options simultaneously**

Also, you can implement both methods simultaneously.  If you have the %'s around it, then it's going to utilize the variable - otherwise it will treat `~` as a command.

```
C:\>:: ECHO (display) THE VALUE OF %~%
C:\>echo %~%
C:\Users\a

C:\>:: ChDir to ~\DESKTOP
C:\>cd /d %~%\Desktop

C:\Users\a\Desktop>:: USE THE ~ COMMAND
C:\Users\a\Desktop>~

C:\Users\a>
```

**One other tip (kinda related):**

This is less likely to be acceptable on a corporate machine, at least on your home PC, to save additional keystrokes, it's not a bad idea to make your `%USERPROFILE%` dir a simple name.  As you can see from my examples above, my user dir is `C:\Users\a` - I used to always have 'aplocher' or 'adamp' and when I changed to a single letter, it was magical.

Answer (score 2):

In Powershell the `%variable%` syntax does not work. You can do this :

```
cd $env:USERPROFILE
```

Comment: You can use `cd ~` in PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

In cmd.exe, you can make `~` work just like `~` in Unix systems with help of [clink](https://chrisant996.github.io/clink/) and its Lua scripts:

1. Install [latest version](https://github.com/chrisant996/clink/releases) of clink.
2. Download [tilde_autoexpand.lua](https://github.com/chrisant996/clink-gizmos/blob/main/tilde_autoexpand.lua) and place it in some directory, let's say:

```
C:\clink\Scripts\tilde-autoexpansion
```

3. Install scripts from that directory with:

```
clink installscripts C:\clink\Scripts\tilde-autoexpansion
```

4. Run `clink set tilde.autoexpand true` to enable it.

After that, `~` should automatically expand to home directory. Test it with e.g. `cd ~`. Restart cmd to reload clink if it doesn't.

Also note that by default to type regular tilde you need to use `~~`. You can change this with `tilde.escape` setting.

Answer (score -1):

Using PowerShell, you have two options.

1. (Option 1) You may try the following method to navigate directories from anywhere provided you know your username and have file directory permissions granted.

```
cd \..\Users\yourUserName\Documents
cd \..\Users\yourUserName\Downloads
cd \..\Users\yourUserName\Desktop
cd \..\Users\yourUserName\music
```

See example below in PowerShell (64bit). I tested this on a Windows 7 Pro 64bit box.

[image: Linux Lilde equivalent on Windows 7 Pro 64 Bit]

2. (Option 2) You can use the tilde character in powershell.

```
cd ~
```

Alternatively, you may install unix-like distribution emulators for Windows such as [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), so you get unix-like environment functionality while using command prompt (CMD) on a Windows OS.