# Is there a windows equivalent to using ~/ as a shorthand symbolizing your home/user directory?

Tags: windows, shortcuts, home-directory, user-folders

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the equivalent of Linux's “~” in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/332871/what-is-the-equivalent-of-linuxs-in-windows)

For example, is there a character I can enter in place of the asterisk in the string "*\Videos" that is equivalent to typing the string "C:\Users\myusername\Videos"?

I'm particularly interested in using this method to jump to my user directory from the Windows key dialog.

Please pardon any butchering of technical terminology.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, in regular windows prompt there is no shorthand notation.
You can use %userprofile% or %homepath%, for example `cd %userprofile%` and `cd %HOMEPATH%\Videos` as per your example

In [Powershell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell), however, you can use the tilde `~`. If you use console a lot I would recommend creating a shortcut to the Powershell rather than regular command prompt

Comment: Yep: I wrote home.bat for myself, it looks like this - @cd /d %userprofile%. So I don't type it at, I just run "home".

Comment: You can create your own environment variables to accomplish something like `./`, but you have to use the `%variable%` notation (e.g. `%./%`)