# Equivalent of ~/.something for windows

Tags: windows

I'm porting an application to Windows and I need to decide where to store user settings and session information on the filesystem. Under linux I put everything under `~/.myapp`. I could do the same on Windows, but I'm wondering what the canonical approach is for this.

Things that will be stored in this directory:

- user settings that need to persist across app lifetimes
- user authentication information
- logs

Comment: %AppData%myapp is the usual spot.  There's some complexity depending on whether the user is attached to a domain and has Roaming enabled, but in my case it points to C:\Users\johnsmith\AppData\Roaming .  Each user has a unique %AppData% folder that's only accessible under that user's login.  There's also %TEMP% for per-app-lifetime data.  I don't suggest putting logs or anything important in %TEMP% because some people like to run Disk Cleanup or similar utilities while other programs are still running.

Comment: You should  use %UserProfile%

Comment: The document with the recommended locations, dating from the introduction of the current naming conventions with Vista, has disappeared from the Microsoft download site. However, a copy can be found here https://www.scribd.com/document/48246732/Windows-File-System-Namespace-Usage-Guidelines

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/1048579/cmd-equivalent-to-cd-to-change-to-c-users-current-user-documents/ http://superuser.com/questions/476274/is-there-a-windows-equivalent-to-using-as-a-shorthand-symbolizing-your-home-u/ http://superuser.com/questions/332871/what-is-the-equivalent-of-linuxs-tilde-in-windows

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The %userprofile% variable is the closest thing to that. It'll expands to your user directory (c:\users\foo). This is probably *not* the canonical place

*However* I believe for this sort of thing %appdata% (which expands to %userprofile%\appdata\roaming)- which essentially is used for the sort of thing that dotfolders are used for or the registry would be more appropriate. This is used *even* if you're not actually on a domain or roaming.

You can find a full list of environmental variables [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749104(v=ws.10).aspx)